# Find overlapping dates in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Each registration has a start_date and end_date. How can I find a registration that overlaps another in any way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer for an overlap test is twice `This.Start` vs `Other.End`, as described here http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap

```
WHERE A.start < B.end
  AND B.start < A.end
```

Change the `<` to `<=` if you deem "touching" dates as overlaps, e.g.

```
Jan1 - Jan13
Jan13 - Jan15
```

Returns overlap for `<=` but not-overlap for `<`

Answer (score 1):

This is just a SQL problem... I think this SQL will do it for you:

```
select r1.* 
from registrations r1, registrations r2
where 
  r1.start_date < r2.start_date
  and r1.end_date > r2.start_date
```

In Rails you'd do this like:

```
registrations = Registration.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Where sql equals the sql code above.

Comment: This looks like it will only find when r2 is completely contained in r1, I think the question was to find any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This finds any range 1 that has *any* overlap between the two ranges, even if one is not entirely contained in the other.

```
select r1.* 
 from registrations r1
 JOIN registrations r2 ON r1.start_date 
                  between r2.start_date
                      AND r2.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has an OVERLAPS operator.

```
CREATE TABLE over_laps
(
  start_date date NOT NULL,
  end_date date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT over_laps_pkey PRIMARY KEY (start_date, end_date),
  CONSTRAINT over_laps_check CHECK (start_date < end_date)
)


insert into over_laps values
('2011-01-10', '2011-01-15'), 
('2011-01-08', '2011-01-09'),
('2011-01-09', '2011-01-10'),
('2011-01-09', '2011-01-11'),
('2011-01-10', '2011-01-12'),
('2011-01-11', '2011-01-13'),
('2011-01-13', '2011-01-15'),
('2011-01-14', '2011-01-16'),
('2011-01-15', '2011-01-17'),
('2011-01-17', '2011-01-19');

select t1.start_date start_1, t1.end_date end_1, 
       t2.start_date start_2, t2.end_date end_2
from over_laps t1
inner join over_laps t2 
  on ((t1.start_date, t1.end_date) overlaps (t2.start_date, t2.end_date))
-- Exclude rows that overlap themselves, a trivial case in a self-joined table.  
where t1.start_date <> t2.start_date and 
      t1.end_date   <> t2.end_date
```