# Find numbers that exist more than once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Inside a MySQL database I store sets of numbers giving only the first and the last one e.g.:

```
id |  from  |  to 
1  | 65.789 | 66.323
2  | 66.151 | 69.298 
etc...
```

I try to figure out a way with PHP and MySQL to find the numbers that exist more than once, e.g. on the above, the numbers from 66.151 to 66.323.

Comment: This is very similar to the "overlapping dates" problem .. e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786062/find-overlapping-dates-in-sql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025688/calculate-missing-date-ranges-and-overlapping-date-ranges-between-two-dates

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.from, b.to FROM mytable a JOIN mytable b ON a.from BETWEEN b.from AND b.to
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. Was editing it and didn't pay enough attention. Shouldn't this have an `or` as well though to catch both? i.e. `a.to between ...`

Comment: @Ben: I *think* it still works because `a` and `b` will join the other way around, won't they?  Grateful for a counterexample if I've overlooked something.

Comment: I'm going to confuse myself but if `a.to` is between the `b` values but `a.from` is not you will not catch that case.

Comment: @Ben: In that case, `a.from<b.from<a.to<b.to` and therefore the tables join the other way around, with `a` and `b` swapped.

Comment: It's too late for me to work out whether your logic is correct :-), but if `a.from < b.from` then `a.from` is not `between b.from and b.to`

Comment: @Ben: Correct, but `b.from` is between `a.from` and `a.to` and therefore the join still takes place when `a` is the record currently in `b` and `b` is the record currently in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
select 
    IF(
    t1.`from` = t2.`from` and t1.`to` = t2.`to`,
    CONCAT('ID: ',t1.id, ' (',t1.`from` ,'-',t1.`to`,') is same as ID: ',t2.id,' (',t2.`from`,'-',t2.`to`,')' ),    
    IF(
        t1.`from` >= t2.`from` and t1.`to` <= t2.`to`,
        CONCAT('ID: ',t1.id, ' (',t1.`from` ,'-',t1.`to`,') is included in ID: ',t2.id,' (',t2.`from`,'-',t2.`to`,')' ),
        CONCAT('ID: ',t1.id, ' (',t1.`from` ,'-',t1.`to`,') overlaps with ID: ',t2.id,' (',t2.`from`,'-',t2.`to`,')' )
    )
) as overlaping
from 
    numbers t1 
join 
    numbers t2 
where 
    t2.`from` <= t1.`to` 
and 
    t2.`to` >= t1.`to` 
and 
    t1.id != t2.id
group by 
    concat( greatest(t1.id,t2.id),'-',least(t1.id, t2.id) )
```

Comment: I think that the `t2.to >= t1.to` needs to be changed to `t2.to >= t1.from`

Comment: @ypercube - yes, thank you. Now it will also include subsets of greater sets

Comment: @ypercube - on the second thought, proved by quick test, no. it wil produce duplicate results. I also added grouping yo avoid duplicate entries for equal sets.

Comment: OK, then your condition is equivalent to `t1.to BETWEEN t2.from AND t2.to`, similar to eggyal's answer. You don't avoid duplicate results this way, you split then into 2 parts. I would prefer the other solution (changing the `t1.id != t2.id` to `t1.id < t2.id`) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I just got this idea, but since you posted your own answer I will stick with my version.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST(a.from, b.from) AS overlap_start
  , LEAST(a.to, b.to)        AS overlap_end
FROM mytable a 
  JOIN mytable b 
    ON  a.id < b.id
    AND a.from <= b.to
    AND b.from <= a.to ;
```

and another option, with a grouping so some results are combined and less rows produced:

```
    SELECT 
        MIN(b.from) AS overlap_start
      , a.to        AS overlap_end
    FROM mytable a 
      JOIN mytable b 
        ON  a.id <> b.id
        AND a.from <= b.from
                  AND b.from <= a.to
                            AND a.to <= b.to
    GROUP BY a.id 
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        b.from AS overlap_start
      , b.to   AS overlap_end
    FROM mytable b 
    WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT *
            FROM mytable a
            WHERE a.id <> b.id
              AND a.from <= b.from
                               AND b.to <= a.to
          ) ;
```